# egrep group characters in quotation

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

I want to get "PRETTY_NAME" of my system from release information file. I used this command in my bash file to get it:

```
SYS_VERSION=$(cat /etc/*-release | egrep  "^PRETTY_NAME=(.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)$")
```

It returns the whole line:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

But I just want the characters inside the double quotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed '/^PRETTY_NAME=/!d;s///;s/"//g' /etc/*-release
```

The first command deletes all lines that don't start with `PRETTY_NAME=`, the second remove the said pattern (empty pattern means use last pattern), the third removes the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Using `lsb_release`:

```
$ lsb_release -ds
Ubuntu 17.04
```

or, in a script,

```
sys_descr=$( lsb_release -ds )
printf 'This is a "%s" system\n' "$sys_descr"
```

`lsb_release` parses the `/etc/os-release` file.  The `-d` flag will give you the "description" of the system, which is exactly what `PRETTY_NAME` in `/etc/os-release` supplies.  The `-s` flag will give you output without any header.

See the manuals for `lsb_release` and `os-release`.

Answer (score 2):

With single ***sed*** expression:

```
sed -n 's/PRETTY_NAME="\(.*\)"/\1/p' /etc/*release
```

The output:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

---

In your case it would look like:

```
SYS_VERSION=$(sed -n 's/PRETTY_NAME="\(.*\)"/\1/p' /etc/*release)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `awk -F '"' '{print $2}'`

Comment: This doesn't give the string *inside* the double quotes, but also the quotes themselves. Better use `"` as delimiter.

Comment: @Philippos you where right thanks for your note

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your command into [`cut -d '"' -f2`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
SYS_VERSION=$(cat /etc/*-release | egrep  "^PRETTY_NAME=(.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)$" | cut -d '"' -f2)
```